# Installing OpenCL on XeonPhi

Tags: opencl, xeon-phi

Because I don't have device to test so I ask this question
If i use OpenCL on XeonPhi I only want install the driver and runtimes of XeonPhi (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers), then OpenCL can run and complier code, is that right ? And how about MPSS (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-manycore-platform-software-stack-mpss-archive#33n-2) i see when deverlop OpenCL on Linux, must install MPSS and driver and runtimes of XeonPhi.
I haven't found a document introduced the detail about using OpenCL on XeonPHi on WindowOS , Can you share with me some document about this ?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers might have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel® Xeon Phi™ coprocessor always runs Linux. However, you can run either Linux or Windows on the host system. Regardless of which operating system you run on your host, you will always install a version of the MPSS.

If you want to run Windows on your host system and use OpenCL with the coprocessor, you would use the [OpenCL™ Runtime 14.2 for Intel® CPU and Intel® Xeon Phi™ coprocessors for Windows* (64-bit)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#phiwin) which would give you a Windows compatible runtime for your host and a Linux compatible runtime for the coprocessor. There is no OpenCL™ Code Builder for Windows, independent of the Intel® INDE and Intel® Media Server Studio, neither of which support the 14.2 version of the runtime.